# Upgrade ffmpeg (or rust) on OSX 10.12 cannot find make

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, rust, homebrew, macos-sierra

Trying to `brew upgrade ffmpeg` on OSX 10.12 Sierra but when it arrived to install `rust` I had the following error:

```
make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk" cannot be located.
clang: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

But `which make` gives `/usr/bin/make` and `xcrun make` is recognized and
`ls -l /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk` gives
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  10 Dec 21  2017 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -> MacOSX.sdk`

How can I force the `rust` install to use `/usr/bin/make` instead of the XTools one? Or something else.

EDIT

I have `rustc 1.46.0` which is the dependency that Homebrew wants `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.46.0 --release-channel=stable`

Comment: One possibility could be using [rustup](https://rustup.rs/), which also helps manage multiple Rust toolchains/versions/components and is in general more powerful than any package manager.

Comment: @Coder-256 I tried that, thanks, but Homebrew still wants to install rust with the same "make" error. `rustup update` gives `stable-x86_64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.46.0 (04488afe3 2020-08-24)`

Comment: That output from rustup is normal, it means that there was no available updates so nothing was changed. Anyway you shouldn’t need to use Homebrew at all if you are using rustup. The rustup installer sets up the `rustup` and `cargo` commands which should be all you need.

Comment: I indicated `rustup update` to show rustup was installed, but the Homebrew upgrade of ffmpeg still tried to install rust (and cargo). I found a workaround, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Homebrew formulae

```
brew edit rust
```

and comment the line

```
ENV["SDKROOT"] = MacOS.sdk_path
```

then Rust can be installed (it's quite long).

Comment: Thanks. I actually just had to do this for `brew edit tcl-tk` due to installing `homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg`